# destroy open item editor or item renderer in flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer, itemeditor

Is it possible to destroy/close open item editor or item renderer of a datagrid in different mxml page?

I heard about the functions `editedItemRenderer` and `destroyItemEditor` on Datagrid. Can I use these functions in different mxml page?

Comment: Please be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing.

Flex Applications do not have the concept of a page in the same way that HTML does.  You probably mean different views, or MXML Components.

All itemEditors are created and destroyed as needed.  If you are not viewing the itemEditor on screen, then likely something else has focus and the itemEditor was destroyed automatically.

In most cases, two components should not talk to each other using anything other than their defined API.  so, you can have one component dispatch an event, then it's parent listen for the event and have that parent call methods on another component [such as a DataGrid].